# How do I load a file containing images into a python array?

Tags: python, pandas, image-processing

Is there a way to use the pandas library to simply load the images (as pixelated data) into a single array?

Comment: There is really no need for 4 rows explaining what you are currently learning, just ask the question mate.

Comment: How is your pandas dataset structured? Do you have a column called "filename" that you can use to find the file on your system? If so, you can probably use [pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/handbook/tutorial.html) to read each image.

Comment: The dataset is actually in an external folder. It's just a bunch of JPG files in a folder than I want to add into an array so that I can perform operations on it. I'm just not sure how to load all those images into an array.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a folder that only contains JPEG images.

First, import everything you'll need

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import imageio
```

Then, set the location of the folder that contains ONLY IMAGES. With this folder location, we will generate the list of full filenames for each and every image.

```
image_folder_path = "D:\\temp\\images"

onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(image_folder_path) if isfile(join(image_folder_path, f))]

full_filenames = [join(image_folder_path,this_image) for this_image in onlyfiles]
```

Then, you can start an empty list, start opening one file at a time and appending them to your list.

```
image_list = []

for this_filename in full_filenames:
    image_rgb_values = imageio.imread(this_filename)
    image_list.append(image_rgb_values.copy())

image_list = np.array(image_list)
```

Now, the variable `image_list` has stored all the images.

This will work best if all images have **identical** dimensions (width x height), but it should also work otherwise.

Hope it helps! =)